# Convert byte array to generic value type?

Tags: c#, generics, types, stream, buffer

I have a `Stream` where I'd like to read data from (as value type segments) and move the position according to the size of the given type (declared as generics).

My current approach:

```
public byte ReadUInt8(Stream stream) {
    return (byte)stream.ReadByte();
}

public ushort ReadUInt16(Stream stream) {
    return (ushort)((ReadUInt8() << 8) | ReadUInt8());
}

...
```

What I'd like to achieve:

```
public TValue Read<TValue>(Stream stream)
    where TValue : struct
{
    var bufferSize    = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TValue));
    var buffer        = new byte[bufferSize];

    if(stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize) == 0)
        throw new EndOfStreamException();

    return (TValue)buffer; // here's where I'm stuck

    // EDIT1: A possible way would be
    //        return (TValue)(object)buffer;
    //        but that feels like kicking puppies :/
}
```

Is this somehow possible? Are there any drawbacks from using `Marshal.SizeOf()` (performance-wise etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (TValue)buffer; // here's where I'm stuck
```

Yes, you have just shifted the problem. From  not having a `Stream.Read<T>()` to not having a  `Convert<T>(byte[])` in the std library.
And you would have to call it like `Read<int>()` anyway so there isn't a direct advantage over `BinaryReader.ReadInt32()`

Now when you want to use it from another generic class/method, the `Read<T>()` syntax is useful but for the implementation you might as well map it to BinaryReader calls. I'm afraid that will require boxing:

```
obcject result = null;
if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(int))
  result = reader.ReadInt32();
else if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(double))
  result = reader.ReadDouble();
else ...

return (TValue) result;
```

Comment: Yes, you have just shifted the problem. < How do I need to understand this? What kind of problem? And yes, the invocation will be done from a generic class.

Comment: You shifted it from no Read<T> to no Convert<T> in the library.

Comment: Well there's the possibility to do `(T) Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T))` but I'm not quite sure in what kind of problems I might run with this.

Comment: **Edit** Just tried it out with an integer -> InvalidCastException :/

Comment: Yes, a `byte[]` does not implement IConvertible. I think you're going to need the object and boxing, but maybe someone will post a better solution.