# C# express a type variable as a type

Tags: c#, generics, types

Let's say I'm working with generic function :

```
public interface IFoo
{
  Type Type;
  TValue Read<TValue>();
}

public class Foo : IFoo {}

var f = new Foo();
```

I'd like to write :

```
var value = f.Read<f.Type>();
```

but this gives error :

> f is a variable but is used like a type

I could write conditionals :

```
object value;
if (f.Type == typeof(bool))
{
    value = f.Read<bool>();
}
if (f.Type == typeof(byte))
{
    value = f.Read<byte>();
}
...
```

but this doesn't really work because it's verbose , may be incomplete if I don't know in advance all possible types , and value is an object instead of the type.

Is there a solution ?

Comment: No you can't do this - what would the type of `value` be? When working with runtime type information you have to do things dynamically until you can cast to a known type. In this case you can add a `object Read(Type t)` method and implement the generic version by delegating to this method.

Comment: What if you make the interface generic?

Comment: strictly speaking, you get an error because of using property where you shouls use: var value = f.Read<typeof(f.Type)>(); / not that i understand overall intention anyways

Comment: will you be reading one type per instance of Foo or you want to read multiple different types during single instance lifetime?

Comment: @BaltoStar ok, so if you know the type at the moment of creating Foo instance and that type stays the same for instanve lifetime then take a look at answer from Helmut. thats your bets way to do it.

Comment: @deezg each instance of `Foo` contains a single internal object stored as `byte[]` that is interpreted as type `TValue` ... please note that  `f.Read<typeof(f.Type)>()` gives same error `f is a variable but is used like a type` ... apparently it's an error if a variable appears anywhere inside the type specifier

Answer (score 2):

If the type is known at the time you create the instance of Foo (and doesn't change afterwards), then a generic interface would be the best solution:

```
public interface IFoo<T>
{
    T Read();
}

public class Foo<T> : IFoo<T>
{
    public T Read()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        byte[] buffer = ...get byte array from wherever...;
        object boxedResult;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms))
            {
                if (type == typeof(int))
                    boxedResult = br.ReadInt32();
                else if (type == typeof(long))
                    boxedResult = br.ReadInt64();
                else if (type == typeof(bool))
                    boxedResult = br.ReadBoolean();
                else if (type == typeof(byte))
                    boxedResult = br.ReadByte();

                // ...
                // other types you want to process
                // ...

                else boxedResult = null;
            }
        }
        if (boxedResult != null)
            return (T)boxedResult;
        else
            throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} not supported", type.Name));
    }
}
```

You use the class like this:

```
var intFoo = new Foo<int>();
var boolFoo = new Foo<bool>();

int intVal = intFoo.Read();
bool boolVal = boolFoo.Read();
```

Comment: show him generic Foo definition also and creation of Foo instance

Comment: @HelmutD type does not change per instance of `Foo` but changing to `IFoo<T>` and `Foo<T>` is not realistic because internally `Foo` is `byte[]`

Comment: "internally Foo is byte[]": You mean, you are reading bytes and want to convert them to the generic type? Unfortunately byte[] doesn't implement the IConvertible interface, so you will have to explicitly convert the bytes to all types that the generic parameter T may take.

Comment: I have added a possible implementation of IFoo, using the solution proposed by Henk Holtermann in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201620. If you get the byte array from a stream in the first place, then you can use this directly, of couse.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are ways to solve this problem [through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/335858) or with [LINQ expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2850366/335858), I think the root cause of your problem is in the poor design of your `IFoo` interface.

If all you need is an `object` result from a read, change the interface to this:

```
public interface IFoo {
    Type Type {get;}
    object Read();
}
```

This would let you avoid using generics where its us needs to be "undone" to get an `object`.

Comment: `object Read();` is useful if just i want to output `object.ToString()` but otherwise i'd have to write a messy conversion function